# UEFI binary written in C not picking text file while running in UEFI

Tags: c, text, binaryfiles, uefi

I have the below code. The efi binary and new.txt is placed in the same location. But looks like fopen is not catching the text file situated in the same directory. What might be the reason?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    FILE* filePointer;
    const char* filename = "new.txt";
    int wordExist = 0;
    const int bufferLength = 255;
    char search[100];
    char line[bufferLength];
    filePointer = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (filePointer != NULL) {
        printf("correct method \n ");
    }
    else {
        printf("not correct \n");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        printf("%d \n", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output I'm getting :
not correct
0
1
2
3
4
5
6

The output I'm expecting:
Correct method
0
1
2
3
4
5
6

Comment: It's unclear how this code relates to UEFI. Can you please show the exact expected result vs actual result?

Comment: output currently: not correct 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 , what i expect is : correct method 0 1 2 3 4 5 6

Comment: I'm qjust checking whether fopen is picking the text file or not, but it is not picking when run in the UEFI shell.

Comment: Please edit the post to update it with that info. "not picking" is very unclear. You should say "fopen fails". Also, call `perror` when `fopen` fails to get a more specific error description.

Comment: Thaanks, perror is giving : fopen() failed: No such file or directory, but the file is clearly present in the same directory itself.

Comment: I would trust `fopen`. The working directory may not be what you think it is. If on a posix system then call `getcwd` to confirm the current working directory.

Comment: These are not UEFI interfaces - what framework are you using to build the code?

Comment: Hi all, I understood the issue. my binary is located inside FS0:\binaries\ but the binary is looking for files only at FS0. Why is this?. Does UEFI understand file structure?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using edk2 with edk2-libc.

Make sure to add "DevShell" to the "[LibraryClasses]" section in your applications .inf file.

If you are trying to run the program without the UEFI shell, fopen will fail.